# Bootstrap cols shorter than content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, height, overflow, responsive

Lately, I've run into a problem when trying to get my web aps to work with small devices.  Even then, this doesn't seem to always be an issue, it will depend upon the orientation of the phone.  What I'm seeing is say I have a Bootstrap 4 ROW with a col-3 col-6 col-3 setup.  The center col has more height and includes images where fade in and out of opacity, so the height is constant.  When BS does its thing for smaller displays, the first col-3 breaks properly, leaving space for the col-6.  The problem is the col-6 seems to break at the col-3 height and I get over lapping.  When using the dev tools, I can see this is the case but I dont want to set a hard height because that makes the spacing go weird and defeats the whole BS purpose.  Here are some examples:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0vh 5vw;">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 text-center wow fadeInLeft">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-eye features-icon"></i>
      <h2 style="color: white; font-size: 3vmin">Something</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center  wow" style="height: 53vh;">
    <img id="img1" src="myImage.jpg" alt="dashboard" class="img-fluid img1" style="margin-top: 3vh; 
       display:block; position:absolute; opacity: 1;">
    <img id="img2" src="~/anotherImage.png" alt="dashboard" class="img-fluid img2" style="margin-top: 
       3vh; display:block;position:absolute; opacity: 0;">                   
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 text-center wow fadeInRight">
    <div>
     <i class="fa fa-database features-icon"></i>
     <h2 style="color: white; font-size: 3vmin">More blah blah</h2>                    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This image shows where col is over lapping (blue icon)

BTW, I've set the center col height because without it, I get no height to that col.  I've tried manipulating it, but it seems that whatever I do, it will fix it for one layout orientation and mess up the others. I must be missing something simple in BS.  Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That row has an inline style defining a margin, maybe the view units are causing the problem. Try changing that around to % or px to see how it behaves or remove that margin all together and use bootstrap's margin utilities. Other thing I can think of would be to try and wrap the overlapping elements in two different .container-fluid

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up doing what I consider a cheat using jQuery.  I gave the col div an id of #mcsCol and put this in my $(document).ready(function)

```
$("#mcsCol").css({ "height": $("#img1").css("height") });
```

So essentially, it will check the height of the image and set the col to the same height.  If you have a more native solution, I'd love to see it.